# Twitter Share data-text get value via Jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter, syntax

I am trying to get the value of my data-text from my twitter share button, I came up with this code:

```
var twitterTitle = $('.twitter-share-button').attr("data-text");
alert(twitterTitle);
```

but it was alerts undefined. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

should be

```
var twitterTitle = $('.twitter-share-button').data("text");
```

Comment: Still getting undefined

Comment: please post the HTML for the button. if it has an attribute named data-text with an assigned value, then something else is going on.
your not getting $ is undefined are you?